# Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for log output matching '.*DATABASE IS READY TO USE!.*\s'

Tags: spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am trying to config oracle test container in spring boot app(in windows) and faced following exception:

```
[-] INFO  [gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim] - Container gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim is starting: 3e76a299c6e2757cf77356b3fb8be627907e22286ac79eda9311448d2e65623a

[-] ERROR  [gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim] - Could not start container

    Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for log output matching '.*DATABASE IS READY TO USE!.*\s'
```

The config class is as follows:

```
    @DataJpaTest(showSql = true)
    public abstract class AbstractTestSharedOracleContainer {
        
        protected static OracleContainer oracleContainer;
        
        static {
            oracleContainer = getInstance();
            oracleContainer.start();
        }
        
        private synchronized static final OracleContainer getInstance() {
            if (oracleContainer == null)
                oracleContainer = new OracleContainer(DockerImageName.parse("gvenzl/oracle-xe:slim"));
            return oracleContainer;
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: And, well, _did_ the database inside the container start successfully? When you read its logs, what's there?

Comment: I updated the exception, "Could not start container" @CharlesDuffy

Comment: You need to read the logs from the copy of Oracle, not from the Java program that's trying to start it.